# Multi layer package in python

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have a python package with packages in it. This explanation seems strange, so I'll include my package's structure:

```
package\_
    __init__.py
    subpackage1\_
        __init__.py
        file1.py
    subpackage2\_
        __init__.py
        file2.py
```

(I'm simplifying it for easier understanding).

The `__init__.py` on the top level looks like this:

```
__all__ = ["subpackage1", "subpackage2"]
```

And, for some reason, when importing the package, it dosen't recognise anythong from `file1.py` or `file2.py`. Any ideas how to fix it?

If you need more details, here's the project on github: https://github.com/Retr0MrWave/mathModule
. The directory I called `package` is `mathmodule_pkg` in the actual project

Comment: `__all__` is used when doing `import * from package`. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @KyleWillmon that's what I'm trying to do, but it does not work, and I'm asking how to fix it with this question

Comment: the name of the subpackages includes upper levels. For the import system, there is no package `subpackage2`, there is only `package.subpackage2`. What's commonly done is that specific classes or functions within a subpacakge are rebound into the top-level `__init__.py` to make their importing easier, like `from package.subpackage2.file1 import my_func`, and then having `my_func` directly in `__all__` and enabling an import like `from package import my_func`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Arne Yep, exactly. Thanks. Pease post this as an answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling the `__all__` field with names does not make imports possible, it merely serves as a hint of what you mean to make importable. This hint is picked up by star-imports to restrict what is imported, and IDEs like pycharm also use it to get an idea of what is and isn't exposed - but that's about it.

If you want to enable top-level imports of your nested classes and functions, you need to

1. import them into the top-level `__init__.py`
2. bind them to names that can be used for the import
3. optionally, reference said names in `__all__` to make the API nice and obvious

Using the project you're referencing as an example, this is what it would look like:

**mathmodule_pkg/__init__.py**

```py
import mathmodule_pkg.calculus.DerrivativeAndIntegral  #1

integral = mathmodule_pkg.calculus.DerrivativeAndIntegral.integral  #2

__all__ = ['integral']  # 3
```

Using the very common form of `from some.package import some_name` we can combine steps 1 and 2 and reduce the potential for bugs when re-binding the name:

```py
from mathmodule_pkg.calculus.DerrivativeAndIntegral import integral  # 1 and 2

__all__ = ['integral']  # 3
```

---

Using either form, after installing your package the following will be possible:

```py
>>> from mathmodule_pkg import integral
>>> integral(...)
```