# How to compile a library for a multi-layered Python class structure

Tags: python, lib

**The Challenge**

I am working on a Python project that will act as a translation layer for the SCPI command line interface on scientific instruments.

It is similar to the concept described in [Multi layer package in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893255/multi-layer-package-in-python) however my situation is slightly more complex and I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

The following is a representation of my project structure (I am happy to change it if it is required):

[image: Project Structure Representation]

**Some things to keep in mind**

- The names of the files in **translator_lib.instruments.supplierX.moduleX** are only *class1.py, class2.py and class3.py*, the rest of the filename is for reference to describe where they are derived from.
- Many of the modules and classes inside of supplier1 and supplier2 have the same names (as in the example).
- Every directory contains a __init__.py file

[image: init.py files in each directory (not all expanded)]

**The __init__.py files (based on the example layout) look as follows (Note I only have one module for testing)**

*translator_lib\__init__.py*

```
from .instruments import supplier1

__all__ = ['supplier1']
```

*translator_lib\instruments\__init__.py*

```
from .supplier1 import module1

__all__ = ['module1']
```

**What I'm trying to do**

Compile three libraries called *my_translator_lib*, *supplier1_translator_lib* and *supplier2_translator_lib*.

**Reason**

The development team would import *my_translator_lib* to do what they need to, but if we want to send sample code to supplier1, we want to send them the *supplier1_translator_lib* and they should only be able to import *supplier1_translator_lib*

**Example 1 : *Developer***

```
from translator_lib.instruments import supplier1
from translator_lib.instruments import supplier2


class DoStuff:

  __init__(self):
    self.sup1_class1 = supplier1.module1.class1.class1()
    self.sup2_class1 = supplier2.module1.class1.class1()
```

**Example 2 : *Supplier 1***

```
from supplier1_translator_lib import module1
from supplier1_translator_lib import module2


class DoStuff:

  __init__(self):
    self.class1 = module1.class1.class1()
    self.class2 = module1.class2.class2()
```

I've tried multiple combinations and sections from [How to create a Python library](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f) and [Deep dive: Create and publish your first Python library](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-dive-create-and-publish-your-first-python-library-f7f618719e14).  I manage to create a library and install it, but ultimately I can only import *my_translator_lib* and nothing else is visible or available.

Any help in this regard would be truly appreciated.

Comment: The approach would be to isolate base classes and build a package, then build your 2nd library with adding dependency in your setup.py , so that also gets installed when some one uses translator_lib.

Answer (score 0):

have you created the `__init__.py` files?
you need to have then in every subfolder to your module.

Files named `__init__.py` are used to mark directories on disk as Python package directories. Try to follow this:

```
mydir/spam/__init__.py
mydir/spam/module.py
```

If this not solve your problem, as a last resource you can try to `sys.path.append('path_to_other_modules')`

Comment: yes every directory contains a \_\_init\_\_.py file (I've updated my post to include that information)